# The [filepicker] tag has had its basic tag rights infringed upon by filepicker.io

Tags: support, tags, ambiguous-tags

> For those of you who hate fun, Ending the Fourth is what I think needs should happen. I guess the question is "can file pickers in general and filepicker.io be separated?"

Once upon a time there was a tag named [filepicker](/questions/tagged/filepicker). It lived happily in the orangey-hued meadows of Stack Overflow, minding its own business. It never needed to worry about whether the grass was greener on the other side. Oh, it wasn't a wildly popular tag like some of the other tags, but it served its purpose and was content with its dozen questions. (Personally I feel it was hard done by in only having that few friends, but that is another matter.)

One day a Nice Nifty New Service going by the name of [filepicker.io](http://filepicker.io) came along. It seemed pretty cool, but alas! it trampled upon that poor [filepicker](/questions/tagged/filepicker) tag. I don't blame the filepicker.io team, but the fact remains that their brand infringed upon the tag rights of [filepicker](/questions/tagged/filepicker). From about July onwards, most or all of the questions filed in [filepicker](/questions/tagged/filepicker) were about filepicker.io rather than file pickers in general. And [filepicker](/questions/tagged/filepicker) didn't know what to do with these questions!

Now you get to Choose your Ending! (™, probably.)

## Ending the First: filepicker.io gets court and fined and then died

[filepicker](/questions/tagged/filepicker) went to court, suing on some form of trademark infringement or something else. Maybe it was the violation of basic tag rights. I can't remember what it was, actually. Check in Hansard to find out.  Anyway, they won and filepicker.io died and [filepicker](/questions/tagged/filepicker) got to maintain its integrity.

## Ending the Second: filepicker.io gets crushed

[filepicker](/questions/tagged/filepicker) got several million dollars from a VC or some such investor (I suspect is was successful because it had no business plan), hired lots of people to ask questions about file pickers in general and quickly overwhelmed filepicker.io. A few months later the latter service out bought it for $7,288.58.

## Ending the Third: [filepicker](/questions/tagged/filepicker) dies a lonely death

[filepicker](/questions/tagged/filepicker) wept bitterly for the days of yore, but alas, it was no good. Eventually it ran away to sea and finally ended up cast onto a desert island. This record has been found, written by itself:

> There I eked out a miserable existence, feeding on sand and gravel and dressing myself in cactus plants. Years passed. Eating sand and mud slowly undermined my robust constitution. I fell ill. I died. I buried myself.
>
> Would that others who write sea stories would do as much.

## Ending the Fourth: the boring, almost realistic one

A new lobbying group was started, *The Friends of [filepicker](/questions/tagged/filepicker)*. It lobbied assorted governments<sup>*</sup> and the League of Tags (or was it the United Tags?) and got an injunction against filepicker.io, that it should move to [filepicker.io](/questions/tagged/filepicker.io).

Then all was resolved; file pickers in general should use [filepicker](/questions/tagged/filepicker) and the service filepicker.io should use [filepicker.io](/questions/tagged/filepicker.io).

And they all lived happily ever after.

---

<sup>*</sup> I know the US has the Republicans and the Democrats, but I haven't even got a clue which is which or which Obama is affiliated with or which is which colour; don't bother enlightening me.

Comment: You know we hate fun right? Any chance you could formulate this as a clear question. Perhaps a tl;dr at the top?

Comment: OK, I added a bit at the top for that purpose.

Comment: Uhm ... the [tag:filepicker] wiki mentions filepicker.io (and there's no [filepicker.io] wiki. Someone 'ought to fix that. (Someone who knows more about this than me, that is).

Answer (score 7):

In keeping with the theme of the question, I've made an Executive Decision and created the [filepicker.io](/questions/tagged/filepicker.io) tag.  (It seemed reasonable, since [filepicker](/questions/tagged/filepicker) is already a thing, and [filepicker.io](/questions/tagged/filepicker.io) is a related but different thing.)  I also retagged a handful of questions that were obviously about the Web service, but someone who knows more about it will want to go through the [filepicker](/questions/tagged/filepicker) questions and retag the ones that I missed.

Comment: Thanks. I'm so glad that [filepicker] didn't need to attempt to subsist on sand and gravel. However, I imagine this is going to be an ongoing problem, too. You never can convince people to tag their questions correctly, whatever goes in the tag wikis and excerpts.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan It probably will be a stuggle, but `filepicker.io` popping up in the list of tags automatically as people type will help a lot.  Thanks for suggesting it.

Comment: As a member of the filepicker.io team, deepest apologizes to the citizens of filepicker-landia. Thanks for the help in resolving this; I'm happy to use the filepicker.io tag from now on and steer our users toward it as well. Are there other things I can do to make things better?

Comment: @LiyanChang That's no problem.  Chris caught it before the problem was too big to fix easily.  Asking your users to tag their questions `filepicker.io` would be a big help.  Thanks!